# Windows 7 Max-Window won't max all the way

Tags: windows-7, display

I have a problem that comes up every once in a while. Sometimes when playing a game that changes the screen resolution and plays at full-screen, and then crashes, my windows don't perform normally.
The resolution is restored OK, but when I try to max a window, it won't fill the right 4" of the screen. I can still see the desktop wallpaper fills the entire monitor though. And if the window is not maxed, then I can manually size the window to fit the whole desktop.
I run a dual monitor and this happens on both monitors. Each monitor is a different brand, so I don't think it's the drivers, which are up to date.
What it appears to be is Windows thinks there's something docked to the right and it maxes to that imaginary border.

So, here's the question: How can I reset the screen borders so that max windows works again? I have tried changing the resolution, the refresh rate, and changing the image from landscape to portrait. The only thing that ever works is rebooting, which is a pain. Does anyone have a better idea? I hope this all makes sense. Thanks.

P.S. Running Windows 7 x86 with a GeoForce 210 graphics adapter.

Comment: Does this happen *only* with windows that were currently open, or to new ones opened after the crash? Also, does logging off/back on fix, or strictly rebooting?

Comment: It happens to all windows. Both old & new. Haven't tried logging off yet. Will try that next time this happens.

Answer (score 0):

The *only* time I ever saw something like this on a friend's laptop, running DOSBox and quitting fixed it since it changes video modes. If not DOSBox (portable version available [here](http://portableapps.com/apps/games/dosbox_portable)), perhaps you can try a video player that changes resolution on full screen, but I'm not sure that will work equally well, (Actually, even the DOSBox "solution" might have been a fluke, but no way to confirm since the problem never reared its head again).

Also, you really should try and fix whatever it is that's causing such frequent crashes.